# terminal message on opening "conda: command not found"

Tags: uninstall, anaconda

I have successfully uninstalled anaconda from Ubuntu 18.04 but now when I open terminal it shows the message
        conda: command not found
        bash: /home/muddy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or 
        directory
        bash: /home/muddy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or 
        directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to erase the appended line by Anaconda in your `.bashrc`. Looks like:

```
. /home/muddy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```